# onTap keeps getting called again and again

Tags: flutter, dart

I had an onTap function for an InkWell with the following code:

```
onTap: () async {
  setState(() {
    hasPressedLogIn = true;
    print(hasPressedLogIn);
  });
  var loginData = await lib.login(username, password);
  print('got loginData');
  setState(
    () {
      if (password == '' && username == '' ||
          password == '' ||
          username == '') {
        loginText = 'username or password empty';
      } else {
        utils.saveLoginData(username, password, loginData!.token.session,
            loginData.token.refresh);
        print('saved login data');
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => HomePage(
              token: loginData.token.session,
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    },
  );
},
```

Now, the code executes perfectly for the first time and the app successfully navigates to the next page without any error, however the onTap function doesn't stop despite having done it's job resulting in the rate limit being exceeded. The function seems to loop around the line

```
var loginData = await lib.login(username, password);
```

which later on exceeds the login attempt limit. How am I supposed to stop these unnecessary calls?

Comment: try refactor so that onTap, first validates the fields, then setState loginText if needed, otherwise call login, validate the response and saveLoginData and push to new route (no need for that to be in setState, it causes a rebuild unesseserily

Answer (score 0):

Change it to this:

```
 onTap: () async {
  if (password == '' && username == '' || password == '' ||  username == '') {
    setState(() {
    loginText = 'username or password empty';
    });
   } else {
   setState(() {
    hasPressedLogIn = true;
   });
    print(hasPressedLogIn);
    utils.saveLoginData(
    username,
    password,
    loginData!.token.session,
    loginData.token.refresh);
    print('saved login data');
   var loginData = await lib.login(username, password);
   print('got loginData');
   Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
   builder: (context) => HomePage( token: loginData.token.session,),),);}
 },
```

Comment: Hey, I tried your code but, the line `var loginData = await lib.login(username, password);` is below the saveLoginData() and so it was giving me an error saying that loginData has still not been initialized and so I moved the line above the saveDataLogin and it again returned to being the issue, that is calling the function again and again,

Answer (score 0):

```
onTap: () async {
if(hasPressedLogIn == false){
                              setState(() {
                                hasPressedLogIn = true;
                                print(hasPressedLogIn);
                              });
                              var loginData =
                                  await lib.login(username, password);
                              print('got loginData');
                              setState(
                                () {
                                  if (password == '' && username == '' ||
                                      password == '' ||
                                      username == '') {
                                    loginText = 'username or password empty';
                                  } else {
                                    utils.saveLoginData(
                                        username,
                                        password,
                                        loginData!.token.session,
                                        loginData.token.refresh);
                                    print('saved login data');
                                    Navigator.push(
                                      context,
                                      MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (context) => HomePage(
                                          token: loginData.token.session,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    );
                                  }
                                },
                              );}
else{
Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 1500), () {
//after a limited duration you will  be able to tap it again
 setState(() {   
                                hasPressedLogIn = false;
                                print(hasPressedLogIn);
  });

});
}
                            },
```